# How I can pass php variable to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show title variable in ajax

*PHP*

```
<?php

$title = "Test-1";

?>
```

*Ajax*

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
        if ($(".main-input-box").val().length > 0) {
            $(".btn").load("results.php", {ID: $(".main-input-box").val()}, function (data, result) {
                alert($title);
            });
        }
    });
```

thanks.............................

Comment: `alert('<?="Test-1"?>');`

Comment: It's value I need read from variable

Comment: `alert('<?=$title?>');`

Comment: not working....

Comment: make sure that your script has access to that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Passing the value to the client

PHP runs on the server. Browser-side JavaScript runs in the browser. To communicate between them you have to send data over HTTP.

To include the contents of the variable in the response, echo it.

```
<?php

$title = "Test-1";
echo $title;

?>
```

## Alerting the value

The purpose of jQuery's load function is to make an Ajax request and put the response as the content of an element.

If you want to alert it, don't use `load`. Use `post` instead.

```
$.post("results.php", {ID: $(".main-input-box").val()}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I'll try use post

Comment: It's working if I put data inside alert but don't working when put php variable

Comment: @zaiej — As I said "PHP runs on the server. Browser-side JavaScript runs in the browser. To communicate between them you have to send data over HTTP."

Comment: Your JavaScript program can't read a variable from the PHP program because it is a **different program** (and probably also running on a different computer).

Comment: I want when load php variables return to javascript for show in elements , I can do that via echo but It's not well for me

Comment: @Quentin gave the right way to go, why do you still do `alert($title)` when it is written `alert(data)`?

Comment: if I write data It's will show all echo. I thought ajax will solve my problem but I was wrong :(

Comment: I have a idea but It's crooked way , the idea is when paste data in echo , I'll put '@@@' shortcut in every echo then in javascript I'll cut them in arraylist

Comment: If you want to send multiple pieces of data, then use a standard structured data format like JSON.

Comment: can you leave example ?

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago, I wrote PHP... I'm not sure its your ans...

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    if ($(".main-input-box").val().length > 0) {
        $(".btn").load("results.php", {ID: $(".main-input-box").val(), title: "<?php echo $title ?>"}, function (data, result) {
            alert($title);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your php code and JavaScript code in same file then you can access it in JavaScript as

```
var title = "<?= $title ?>";
```

If JavaScript is in separate js file then before loading that JavaScript file in php and after assigning value to $title add

Main.php

```
<?php
$title = "test";
?>
<script>
var title = "<?= $title ?>";
alert (title);
</script>
```

Then you can alert (title)

Comment: Does your JavaScript code in php file or in a separate js file?

Comment: I have 2 php files , first file It's main file and javascript inside this file , second file It's for get data from server

Comment: "not working" is not helping you since you don't give us any error message. You should edit your question with your tries and error messages